# Plesk auto update crashes FastCGI support

Tags: fastcgi, plesk, parallels

Normally I use PHP as FastCGI. My Plesk panel is auto-updated yesterday from v11.0.9 #55 to #56.
After that update FastCGI soesn't work, but Apache PHP module works.

When I activate FastCGI I get thousands of this error:

```
[Fri Aug 09 21:50:02 2013] [warn] [client 5.47.201.9] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Aug 09 21:50:02 2013] [error] [client 5.47.201.9] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

I found this in Parallel's forum: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?289665-After-Upgrade-to-11-5-Fast-Cgi-Stop-Working
but it didn't help for Plesk 11.

I found this: http://kb.parallels.com/en/6380
At the end of the `/etc/psa/psa.conf` file I added `CGI_PHP_BIN /usr/bin/php-cgi` and restarted server, it didn't worked.

My web server now works with apache-php but it kills my site. Please help.

Solution: Regarding to @Oleg Neumyvakin's questions I checked many things and found out that current "php.ini" file is inconsistent with new PHP version. I copied PHP 5.4's php.ini file to /etc/php.ini and problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SElinux?
2. What is permissions on `/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper`?

   should be -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3660 Jun  6  2012 /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
3. What in `/var/log/apache2/suexec.log` or `/var/log/httpd/suexec_log` ?
4. Permissions on suexec ? Find all files, check permissions: `find / | grep suexec`
5. Custom php.ini on domain / custom php settings on domain? Is their is compatible with current PHP version?
6. What happens if run php script in cli mode like: `php -c /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/etc/php.ini /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/index.php`
7. [Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153518/connection-reset-by-peer-mod-fcgid-error-reading-data-from-fastcgi-server)