# Can't Figure Out Two Repeating Errors in Apache Logs

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, error-handling

I keep getting the following two errors in my apache log and cannot find a fix for them. I'm pretty new to server-side issues so am hoping someone can help me out with this one(or two). Thanks in advance!

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
```

It's a Wordpress website using WooCommerce, and whatever this error is, it's slowing down any xml product imports(updates) to a grinding halt. I have root access, and am using FCGI. I'm also finding a large server load that does not seem to be related to any of the Wordpress plugins.

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been struggling with this issue for the last few days and am about to print off my error logs, take them outside, and then BURN them!:)

Comment: Try taking a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153518/connection-reset-by-peer-mod-fcgid-error-reading-data-from-fastcgi-server