# Xdebug and FastCGI on Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, fastcgi

I'm trying to install Xdebug on my remote dev site.
I have the following in my php.ini file:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
```

I have set the port to 9001 because I understand that the default (9000) will conflict with FastCGI.

But this is not working. With these settings I get and internal error and the following logged:

```
[Fri Nov 07 15:37:53 2014] [warn] [client 162.201.236.210] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Nov 07 15:37:53 2014] [error] [client 162.201.236.210] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

**Update:** I've tried changing [FcgidBusyTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12192622/897523), but that didn't help.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set CDebug to automatically accept connections, autostart on request and set the right server IP.

You have also set a pre-shared key between your debug client and the XDebug instance.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey="my_key"
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try the autostart when I get back to work on Monday, but as for the idekey, I haven't even gotten that far. This should be loading in the browser with xdebug, right?  Or does it ONLY give a valid response when accessed by an ide with the key? That doesn't seem right.  Also, according to http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings, when remote_connect_back is ON then remote_host is ignored. I understand it's a security risk but I was just trying to get something to work. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey got back to work and tried the xdebug.remote_autostart, but it didn't work.  Here is what I currently have, but does not work: zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so   :    
xdebug.remote_enable = On   :   
xdebug.remote_autostart=On   :   
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp   :   
xdebug.remote_host = myIP   :   
xdebug.remote_port = 9001