# php does not work always returns 500 error

Tags: php

I host 3 web site on an vps.
each has a phpt test script

```
a1.com/test.php

a2.com/test.php

a3.com/test.php
```

a1.com/test.php

a2.com/test.php

work well

but when I call

a3.com/test.php

it always report error

```
[Wed Jan 28 01:01:52.801563 2015] 
[fcgid:warn] [pid 27783] (104)Connection reset by peer: 
[client ***.***.27.***:50211] 
mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Wed Jan 28 01:01:52.801651 2015] [core:error] [pid 27783] 
[client ***.***.27.***:50211] 
End of script output before headers: test.php
```

your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking on personal experience, make sure that the directory/file permissions are set properly on a3.com/test.php. If not set properly they can result in a 500 error

Comment: all three sites have same permission on each directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153518/connection-reset-by-peer-mod-fcgid-error-reading-data-from-fastcgi-server <- worth a look other than that I'm pretty worthless

Comment: Thanks they are not same reason, each site;s .conf almost same but only one site has the php error above