# WordPress 500 (Internal Server Error) sending request to load-scripts.php

Tags: php, wordpress, cgi, fastcgi, plesk

I'm facing a problem for days now, Each time I try to edit a page with Thrive Architect I get 500 (Internal Server Error).

I get this on the page:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

As it says, I checked the `error_log` and found these related errors:

```
[Thu Sep 20 16:48:23 2018] [fcgid:warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client ] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://www.website.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2335&action=architect&tve=true
[Thu Sep 20 16:48:23 2018] [core:error] [pid ] [client ] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: https://website.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2335&action=architect&tve=true
```

I get this in the console:

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,hoverIntent,utils,common,admin-bar,underscore,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,mox&load[]=iejs,plupload,wp-plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable&ver=4.9.8:4 GET https://website.com/about-us/?tve=true&tcbf=994d642265 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The server is Plesk.

I tried the following:
1- Increasing PHP and server timeout ..etc:

PHP:

```
max_execution_time = 3600
```

Server:

```
FcgidIOTimeout 3600
FcgidIdleScanInterval 400
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidBusyScanInterval 400
FcgidZombieScanInterval 12
FcgidErrorScanInterval 12
```

2- Replace WordPress folders(wp-admin, wp-includes) with the latest version on wordpress.org.

3- Renaming the `.htaccess`.

4- Checked files/folders permissions.

But none of these methods solved the issue.

Are there are other methods to solve the problem?

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you check your PHP version? Or enable debug and check `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in wp-config.php file.

Comment: Just in case, please check if the "wp-config.php" file has following values set properly. 
AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY, LOGGED_IN_KEY, NONCE_KEY, AUTH_SALT, SECURE_AUTH_SALT, LOGGED_IN_SALT, NONCE_SALT

Comment: @hardiksolanki, No I didn't check the version of PHP, But I enabled the debugging mode and it didn't show any related error

Comment: @Bon you need to check your php version first.

Comment: @zipkundan, Yes the file contains all these constants

Comment: @hardiksolanki, PHP version is 7.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection reset by peer: mod\_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153518/connection-reset-by-peer-mod-fcgid-error-reading-data-from-fastcgi-server)

Comment: @cabrerahector, I checked this some days ago and I tried the suggestions, But didn't work